# JSON object interfaced return undefined

Tags: json, angular

i want to create a pipe in Angular 9 that translate my table words in various language.
I have created a JSON file that contains a key and the value for a translation service. I have also created some interfaces for this json file.

> **translate.json**

```
{
"lang":[
    {
      "IT": [
        { "name": "Nome" },
        { "surname": "Cognome" },
        { "email": "E-mail" },
        { "cf": "Codice fiscale" },
        { "phone": "Cellulare" },
        { "age": "Età" },
        { "city": "Città" },
        { "job": "Lavoro" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "EN": [
        { "name": "first name" },
        { "surname": "last name" },
        { "email": "E-mail" },
        { "cf": "Fiscal code" },
        { "phone": "Phone" },
        { "age": "Age" },
        { "city": "City" },
        { "job": "Job" }
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```

> **translateInterface.ts**

```
export interface Lang {
  lang: (Langs)[];
}
export interface Langs {
  IT: (ITEntityOrENEntity)[];
  EN: (ITEntityOrENEntity)[];
}
export interface ITEntityOrENEntity {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  email: string;
  cf: string;
  phone: string;
  age: string;
  city: string;
  job: string;
}
```

> **translate.service.ts**

```
translate(key: string, lang:string) {
    return this.http.get<Langs>('assets/json/translate.json').subscribe((res: Lang) => console.log(res))

    }
```

I have updated the json and the interface, now how i can return one object of the IT array?

Comment: did you typo the `[`at the beginning? Because this is not valid json.

Comment: No, i didn't. I update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues.

1. You don't need to define the properties `IT` and `EN` as arrays in the JSON file. It could very well be plain JS objects.

```
{
  "IT": {
    "name": "Nome",
    "surname": "Cognome",
    "email": "E-mail",
    "cf": "Codice fiscale",
    "phone": "Cellulare",
    "age": "Età",
    "city": "Città",
    "job": "Lavoro" 
  },
  "EN": {
    "name": "first name",
    "surname": "last name",
    "email": "E-mail",
    "cf": "Fiscal code",
    "phone": "Phone",
    "age": "Age",
    "city": "City",
    "job": "Job" 
  }
}
```

2. There is no need for two different interfaces. You could assign one single interface.

```js
export interface Details {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  email: string;
  cf: string;
  phone: string;
  age: string;
  city: string;
  job: string;
}
```

2. You are defining the type as array in `Langs` interface instead of the defined details interface. You could do something like

```js
export interface Langs {
  IT: Details;
  EN: Details;
}
```

3. At the moment you're wrongfully returning the subscription instead of the observable from the function. You could return the observable from the service and subscribe to it the component controller.

Service

```js
translate(language: string): Observable<Details> {
  return this.http.get<Langs>('assets/json/translate.json').pipe(
    map(response => response[language])
  );
}
```

Component

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.translateService.translate('IT').subscribe(
    details => { this.details = details },
    error => { }
  );
}
```

Template

```html
<span>{{ details?.name }}</span>
<span>{{ details?.surname }}</span>
<span>{{ details?.email }}</span>
...
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-json-http-gubmzp)

Comment: The object details return undefined, and the json file give me an error on the comma

Comment: Yes there was a syntax error in the JSON file, I've since updated the code. Please try now.